# Codename one Facebook login email = null

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, codenameone

I've managed to get the login with facebook working using FacebookConnect. I then try to pull the user's name and email address. I manage to get their name however their email address is blank. I tried it using my Facebook account where I have set my email address to be public. I also added the permissions ios.facebook_permissons = "email", "public_profile", "user_birthday" and the same for android. Here is my code

The login

```
public void facebookLogin() {
    final Login fb = FacebookConnect.getInstance();
    fb.setClientId("964865683621261");
            fb.setClientSecret("1fb729a93d96bb8700f2c879f520052b");
            fb.setRedirectURI("http://kyven.co.za");
            FaceBookAccess.setPermissions(new String[]{"user_birthday", "email", "public_profile"});
            fb.setCallback(new LoginCallback(){
                @Override
                public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
                    Dialog dg = new Dialog();
                    dg.setTitle("Login failed");
                    dg.show();
                }
                @Override
                public void loginSuccessful() {
                    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
                            ip.setUIID("InfiniteProgress");
                            final Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
                    Preferences.set("token", fb.getAccessToken().getToken());
                    final FacebookData data = new FacebookData();
                    data.fetchData(Preferences.get("token", (String) null), new Runnable(){

                        public void run() {
                            String email = data.getEmail();
                            Dialog.show("hello " + data.getName(), data.getEmail(), "OK", null);
                            String fullName = data.getName();
                            String[] args = { email, fullName};
                            String[] keys = { "email", "password"};
                            int id = postRequest(args, keys, "facebook_login.php");
                            if (id != 0) {
                                Preferences.set("userId", id);
                                setUpMainPage();
                                Hashtable meta = new Hashtable();
                                meta.put(com.codename1.push.Push.GOOGLE_PUSH_KEY,
                                    1276);
                                Display.getInstance().registerPush(meta, true);
                            } else {
                                Dialog.show("Error", "There was an error logging you in"
                                    + " please try again later", "OK", null);

                                d.dispose();
                    }
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });
            fb.doLogin();
}
```

Fetching the data

```
public class FacebookData implements UserData {

String name, email;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void fetchData(String token, final Runnable callback) {
    ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                Map<String, Object> parsed = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
                name = (String) parsed.get("name");
                email = (String) parsed.get("email");
            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                callback.run();
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {

            }
        };
        req.setPost(false);
        req.setUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me");
        req.addArgumentNoEncoding("access_token", token);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req);
}

}
```

Comment: @cbroe this is a Codename One question not a javascript question...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog this is a general API version issue, and does not depend on what specific language or SDK you use. The duplicate contains the explanation of the general issue; how to ask for the fields when using a specific SDK is something the developer that has happily slept through these changes until now, can at least go look up in the relevant documentation themselves now please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-2.html

> When you handle your own user list and a user signs in thru
>   registration, you can generally ask that user anything. However, when
>   the user signs in thru Facebook, Google or any other service then you
>   are at the mercy of that service for user details…​ This is painfully
>   clear with such services that don’t provide even an email address by
>   default when logging in. It is sometimes accessible in Facebook but
>   only for users who didn’t choose to hide it.

Generally Facebook doesn't guarantee access to the email address of the user and often doesn't provide it. You need to use the Facebook id as a unique identifier and if you don't get the email you need to ask the user to give it to you.

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with my code?

Comment: The code is mostly for the simulator and not for the device where the permissions and requirements are specified via build hints.

Comment: Hello shai, how can I ask the user for the permission to get email id. I've the exact code as above and same email problem. In facebook Api explorer, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=id,name,email"- this url gives email id as well but if I use it for android devices, both id & name & email are null

Comment: I discussed this in the facebook integration section in the chat tutorial. Email can be null in facebook and as far as I know there isn't much we can do about it.